# ANTLRWorks v1.4.3 Debugger random behaviour (Can't connect to debugger)

Tags: debugging, antlr

If I debug this grammar:

```
grammar CDBFile;

options {
    language=Java;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
    output=AST;
    k=1;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    IMAG_COMPILE_UNIT;
    MODULE;
}

//@lexer::namespace{Parser}
//@parser::namespace{Parser}

@lexer::header {
}

@lexer::members {
}

@parser::header {
}

@parser::members {
}


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
 
fragment LETTER :
    'a'..'z'
  | 'A'..'Z';
  
MODULE_NAME
    :
    (LETTER)*   
    ;

COLON   
    :   
    ':'
    ;


/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

public
compileUnit
        :   
          (basic_record)* EOF 
        ;

basic_record 
    :
    (
    
      'M' COLON   module_record
    | 'F' COLON function_record
    
    ) ('\n')?
    ;

module_record
    :   
    MODULE_NAME 
    ;

function_record
    :
    function_scope MODULE_NAME '$'
    ;

function_scope
    :
    ('G$' | 'F$' | 'L$')    
    ;
```

With just this input:

```
M:divide
```

the debugger does simply not start saying

- "*Cannot launch the debuggerTab. Time-out waiting to connect to the remote parser*".

**But** using *this* grammar here:

```
grammar Calculator;

options {
//DO NOT CHANGE THESE!
backtrack    = false;
k            = 1;
output       = AST;
ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
//SERIOUSLY, DO NOT CHANGE THESE!
}

tokens {
  // Imaginary tokens
  
  // Root
  PROGRAM;
  
  // function top level
  FUNCTION_DECLARATION;
  FUNCTION_HEAD;
  FUNCTION_BODY;
  
  DECL;
  FUN;
  // if-else-statement
  IF_STATEMENT;
  IF_CONDITION;
  IF_BODY;
  ELSE_BODY;
  
  // for-loop
  FOR_STATEMENT;
  FOR_INITIALIZE;
  FOR_CONDITION;
  FOR_INCREMENT;
  FOR_BODY;
  
  // Non-imaginary tokens
}

@lexer::header {
package at.tugraz.ist.cc;
}

@lexer::members {
}

@parser::header {
package at.tugraz.ist.cc;
}

@parser::members {
}



  //Lexer rules
ASSIGNOP :
  '=';

OR :
  '||';

AND :
  '&&';

RELOP :
  '<'
  | '<='
  | '>'
  | '>='
  | '=='
  | '!=';

SIGN :
  '+'
  | '-';

MULOP :
  '*'
  | '/'
  | '%';

NOT :
  '!';

fragment OPERATORS :
  '<'
  | '>'
  | '='
  | '+'
  | '-'
  | '/'
  | '%'
  | '*'
  | '|'
  | '&';

INT :
  '0'
  | DIGIT DIGIT0*;

fragment DIGIT :
  '1'..'9';

fragment DIGIT0 :
  '0'..'9';

BOOLEAN :
  'true'
  | 'false';

ID :
  LETTER
  (
    LETTER
    | DIGIT0
    | '_'
  )*;

fragment LETTER :
  'a'..'z'
  | 'A'..'Z';

PUNCT :
  '.'
  | ','
  | ';'
  | ':'
  | '!';

WS :
  (
    ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
  )
  
  {
   $channel = HIDDEN;
  };

LITERAL :
  '"'
  (
    LETTER
    | DIGIT
    | '_'
    | '\\'
    | OPERATORS
    | PUNCT
    | WS
  )*
  '"';
  




// parse rules

program :
  functions -> ^(PROGRAM functions)
  ;
  
functions :  
  (function_declaration functions)?
  ;
  
function_declaration :
  head=function_head  '{' declarations optional_stmt return_stmt rc='}' -> ^(FUNCTION_DECLARATION[$head.start, $head.text] function_head ^( FUNCTION_BODY[rc,"FUNCTION_BODY"] declarations optional_stmt? return_stmt))
  ;

function_head :
  typeInfo=type ID arguments -> ^(FUNCTION_HEAD[$typeInfo.start, "FUNCTION_HEAD"] type ID arguments?) 
  ; 

type : 
  
    'int'
    | 'boolean'
    | 'String'
  ;
 
arguments : 
  '(' ! argument_optional ')' !;
  
argument_optional : 
  parameter_list ? -> ^(DECL parameter_list)?  ;
  
parameter_list : 
  type  ID parameter_list2 -> ^(type ID) parameter_list2
  ;

parameter_list2 : 
  (','  type  ID)*  -> ^(type ID)*; 
  

declarations :
  (   type idlist ';' )*  ->  ^(DECL ( ^(type  idlist))*) ;
  
idlist : 
  ( ID idlist2 );
   
idlist2 : 
  ( ',' ! idlist ) ?;
  
optional_stmt :
  ( stmt_list ) ?;

stmt_list : 
  statement statement2;

statement2 : 
  stmt_list ?;

return_stmt : 
   'return' ^  expression ';' ! ;

statement :
  (
    compound_stmt
    | ifThenElse
    | forLoop
    | assignment ';' !
  ) ;
  
ifThenElse :
  (
  'if' '('  ifCondition=expression ')' ifBody=statement 'else' elseBody=statement -> ^(IF_STATEMENT ^(IF_CONDITION $ifCondition) ^(IF_BODY $ifBody) ^(ELSE_BODY $elseBody)) 
  )
;

forLoop :
  (
    'for' '(' forInitialization=assignment ';' forCondition=expression ';' forIncrement=assignment ')' forBody=statement -> 
    ^(FOR_STATEMENT ^(FOR_INITIALIZE $forInitialization) ^(FOR_CONDITION $forCondition) ^(FOR_INCREMENT $forIncrement) ^(FOR_BODY $forBody))
  )
;

compound_stmt :
  '{'! optional_stmt '}' !;

assignment :
  ID ASSIGNOP ^ expression;

expression: andExpression (OR ^ andExpression)*;
andExpression: relOPExpression (AND ^ relOPExpression)*;
relOPExpression: signExpression (RELOP ^ signExpression)*;
signExpression : mulExpression (SIGN  ^ mulExpression)*;
mulExpression : factor (MULOP ^ factor)*;
  
factor :
  (
    factorID
    | INT
    | BOOLEAN
    | LITERAL
    | NOT ^ factor
    | SIGN ^ factor
    | '('! expression ')' !
  );

factorID:    ID 
    ( function_call ->  ^(FUN ID function_call)  
        |   ->  ID
    )
    ;
  
function_call :
  '('! function_call_opt ')' !;
  
function_call_opt :
  extend_assign_expr_list  ? ;
  
extend_assign_expr_list :
  (
    expression
     extend_assign_expr_list1
  ) ;
  
extend_assign_expr_list1 :
  ( ',' ! extend_assign_expr_list ) ? ;
```

parsing an Input like

```
int main()
{ 
  return 0;
}
```

works just fine!

The internet has a lot of suggestions regarding this issue but none of them seem to work. The thing is that the debugger DOES work. Assuming that not the input is the problem here, the grammar has to be it. But if there is a problem with the grammar why would the Interpreter work for both examples?

Any ideas?

## Edit:

I have noticed that for some reason in `__Test__.java` just contains:

```
M:divide
F:G0
```

I also get this output while Interpreting `M:asd`:

```
[13:47:52] Interpreting...
[13:47:52] problem matching token at 1:3 NoViableAltException('a'@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | COLON );])
[13:47:52] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException('s'@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | COLON );])
[13:47:52] problem matching token at 1:5 NoViableAltException('d'@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | COLON );])
```

(even thought the tree is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the debugger only works with the Java target. Since you have C# specific code in your first grammar:

```
@lexer::namespace{Parser}
@parser::namespace{Parser}
```

there are no `.java` classes generated (or at least, none that will compile), and the debugger hangs (and times out).

### EDIT

I see you're using `fragment` rules in your parser rules: you can't. Fragment rules will never become a token on their own, they're only there for other lexer rules.

I've tested the grammar without the C# code in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, and had no issues.

You could try the following:

- restarting ANTLRWorks
- changing the port the debugger listens on (perhaps the port is used by another service, or another debug-run of ANTLRWorks)
- use the most recent version of ANTLRWorks

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I've changed it to `@lexer::header {} @lexer::members {}` but it still does not work. I also noticed that `__Text__.java` contains the input and not the expected `Java` code ..

Comment: I've updated my question with my changes. It still does the same. I Introduced a rule for `fragment LETTER: ...` that says `MODULE_NAME:(LETTER)*;` which should be equivalent to `ID` of the other grammar I posted. I restarted ANTLRWorks and I checked `netstat -aon | find /i "49100"` which is not used by any other application. I use `v1.4.3` to avoid another bug I had experianced with `v1.5.2` (can't remember what that was).

Comment: In your latest edit, the `MODULE_NAME` matches an empty string: lexer rules must never do this, since there are an infinite amount of empty strings in your input. Perhaps delete all generated files (or the entire `output` folder) and try again. Besides that, I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Oh my god I found out why it did not work. I thought that the "TestRig" can contain input data. Instead it must be a valid `Java` class.. (or empty)